# What would be the output of $a + $a++ + $a++ with $a = 1

Tags: php

When `$a = 1` what will be the output of the expression `echo ($a + $a++ + $a++)`

Comment: Rubber duck it and you'll figure it out

Comment: Most languages derived from C (which PHP in a way is) would say it's *undefined behavior*. It all depends on how the operation is sequenced.

Comment: This is what's actually happening under the hood: https://3v4l.org/sqCkW/vld#output

Comment: Also note that `$a++` and `++$a` might give different results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be better explained with a shorter example:

```
$a = 1;
echo $a + $a++;
```

This might look like it should equal 2. The post-increment operator (`$a++`) returns the "before" value of the variable, so it should return 1. And 1+1 equals 2.

However, what's actually happening is that `$a++` is getting evaluated first. So the post-increment operator runs, and returns 1, but by the time the rest of the evaluation happens, `$a` has been incremented to 2. So this ends up evaluating `2 + 1`;

Your example comes down to:

- Run the first `$a++`, returning 1. $a is now 2;
- Evaluate the sum `2 + 1` (the new `$a` value and the return from the post-incr operator), returning 3
- Run the second `$a++` (the end of the line), returning 2 (the value of `$a` before the increment). $a is now 3;
- Evaluate the second sum, `3 + 2`, returning 5

In short, please don't write lines of code like this. They're an interesting experiment if you want to know how PHP works internally, but they aren't remotely intuitive.

**Edit to add:** @Narf's comment below is important too. This is undefined behaviour, and shouldn't be relied upon. In fact, the answer did indeed come out differently in PHP < 5.1. See https://3v4l.org/sqCkW

Comment: This explains how it work*ed*, but is not a definitive answer ... see mine.

Answer (score 3):

The manual for [operators precedence](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) explicitly shows this as an example for undefined behavior:

> Operator precedence and associativity only determine how expressions are grouped, they do not specify an order of evaluation. PHP does not (in the general case) specify in which order an expression is evaluated and code that assumes a specific order of evaluation should be avoided, because the behavior can change between versions of PHP or depending on the surrounding code.
>
> **Example #2 Undefined order of evaluation**
>
> ```
> <?php
> $a = 1;
> echo $a + $a++; // may print either 2 or 3
> ```